# How should i go about proving this set equality?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are three sets. Set X, Y and I am supposed to prove that:

```
(X - Y) - Z = (X - Y) - (Z - Y)
```

I feel like it might have something to do with distribution, but I have never heard of any law in which the distribution of a negative results in something like this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just use the standard approach of taking an element from the set on the left of the inequality and showing it is in the set on the right; then vice versa.

Comment: Isn't that sorta Brute-Force though?

Comment: No, brute force would mean taking every single element in the sets and doing it for each one and one at a time. The approach I am suggesting is the standard way to approach these problems as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example suppose you wanted to prove $A=B$. Then show $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ which implies $A=B$.

Here's a start: Suppose $x\in (X - Y) - Z$. We want to show that this implies $x\in (X - Y) - (Z - Y)$. Obviously $x\in (X - Y) - Z$ means $x\in X-Y$ and $x\notin Z$. But then $x\in X-Y$ means $x\in X \land x\notin Y$. So then since $x\notin Z \land x\notin Y\Rightarrow x\notin Z-Y$ which means $$x\in(X - Y)\land x\notin(Z-Y)\Rightarrow x\in(X-Y)-(Z-Y)$$

Showing this means that $(X-Y)-Z\subseteq (X-Y)-(Z-Y)$. Use the same logic to show  $(X-Y)-(Z-Y)\subseteq (X-Y)-Z$.

Once you have shown each side is a subset of the other, you have proven the equality exists.

Comment: Should it be done with induction?

Comment: @DChalo No need for induction. See the edits to my answer above. Also, it may be worthwhile to read through this: http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/SetProofs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the identity 
$$
A\setminus B=A\cap B^c
$$
and some others basic identities. Hence 
$$
(X\setminus Y)\setminus(Z\setminus Y)=
(X\cap Y^c)\setminus(Z\cap Y^c)=
(X\cap Y^c)\cap(Z\cap Y^c)^c\\
=(X\cap Y^c)\cap(Z^c\cup Y)
=(X\cap Y^c\cap Z^c)\cup(X\cap Y^c\cap Y)\\
=((X\setminus Y)\cap Z^c)\cup(X\cap \varnothing)
=(X\setminus Y)\setminus Z\cup\varnothing
=(X\setminus Y)\setminus Z
$$